# Android list/spinner with data base/table values

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-sqlite, android-spinner

I need here in my app, to list in a spinner all the values from a table, a big one.
In my app I need to choose one specific pipe from a nominal diameter, and the get its real inside diameter, and then do the math go get the flow rate in a velocity.
The maths I was able to make, everything working, but I have to type the inside diameter of the pipe.
Now, I wanna get these values from a source (sql lite or other alternative ? ) with all the values, like in the image attached (cant post yet images, so goes a link).
e.g. I would select one pipe with a nominal diameter of 4", with thickness of 3,91 mm... so my math would use its inside diameter and its weight.
Basically, it would be like in VLOOKUP from excel, I just need to get any value from the row that the main value is that one selected on spinner.

How could I do that ?
Below, a similar table reference:
http://www.tiogapipe.com/assets/files/pipe-chart.pdf

Thanks.
Barata

Comment: Learn how to load data from database and spinners on developer site of android or follow this tutorial to lean it. http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/

Comment: I follow one tutorial now (http://www.androidhive.info/2012/06/android-populating-spinner-data-from-sqlite-database/) and its similar what I need, the problem now is that: I know how to add data and read the data into a spinner.. but where is this database created ? How can I access it to add all my data ? I ask because I have more than 200 rows with 8 columns each... I cant believe I have to insert one row per time.  How should I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get the database and import the data from excel. I just opened the android device monitor to find the database, then I exported it. in excel, i got my tables with more than 500 rows, so I exported in txtTabs and imported on SQLite Browser, the copied back from Device Monitor.

Now its almost working the way I want. I can ready any column and use it in a spinner... But I didn't figure out how to link this chosen item, to get other value from the same row (like the vlookup from excel).
e.g., if I select one item from the 1st column of the"n" row, how could I return the value of the 2nd column of this same "n" row ?

Thanks!
barata